# Hover and Selection tooltips on one point (Google Charts)

Tags: javascript, html, graph, google-visualization

I am creating a Bar Chart in google charts. The data that has been input is very simple, integer values.

I have configured the chart to have hover over functionality with a tooltip that displays a short description of that 'category'.

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Category', 'Number of Artefacts', { role: 'tooltip' }, {role: 'style'}],
['Case Studies', 1, 'Project Summaries (Approach, Constraints, Results)', 'color: light blue' ],
['Communications', 2, 'Internal Comms & Announcements', 'color: light blue'],
['External Studies', 21, 'Consulting or Research Studies (Finance, Banking, Tech)', 'color: light blue' ],
['Functional Knowledge', 31, 'Rules, Policies & Training for better understanding of requirements and products', 'color: light blue' ]
  ]);

 var options = {
    title: 'Active Artefacts',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    tooltiptextStyle: { color: 'black',
                        fontName: 'calibri',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        bold: false,
                        italic: false }
       };
```

In addition to this hover tooltip I would also want to have a selection tooltip on each category whereby it will allow a click through hyperlink to another site.

I first want to know how to insert an extra tooltip (would it just be a case of entering another optional 'role' in the column definitions?) and then also how I would configure one tooltip as hover and the other as selection.

There are examples where tooltip.trigger has been set to 'both' but this does not specify how you can control which tooltip has which trigger.

Comment: You cannot have two different tooltips for a given data point that trigger under different conditions - the API supports only one tooltip per point.

Comment: Thanks asgallant I ended up using a selecthandler to perform the click through.